# Bundled kotlin-stdlib gets ignored on runtime in IDEA plugin

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

#### Context

I have built an IntelliJ plugin that relies on moshi 1.13.0.
In package `com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect` at line 269 `propertyTypeClassifier.isValue` is used. The [`isValue`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/is-value.html) property is available since Kotlin 1.5.

#### Symptoms

When running on newer IDEA based IDEs (2021.2 and up) with kotlin-stdlib 1.5.10 or higher bundled, everything works just fine.
The problem occurs when trying to run my plugin on Android Studio (latest stable release being 2021.1.1.1 patch 3 bumblebee) and other IDEs based on IDEA 2021.1 or older.
Whenever my [openapi-generated](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/kotlin.md) kotlin SDK (which requires aforementioned Moshi) tries to deserialize the server's response, I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean kotlin.reflect.KClass.isValue()'` fatal error thrown by the ide.

#### What has been tried

Since it seems to be a `kotlin-stdlib` related error, I assumed that for some reason my plugin doesn't get the correct version bundled, so:

- I've tried to update all dependencies and make 100% sure `kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10` is the ***only*** version visible in both direct and transitive dependencies listed by `gradlew :dependencies` using various ways to force that in there.
- added the latest `kotlin-stdlib` as top level dependency (tried both compile scope and `implementation` which theoretically adds runtime to a dependency's scope afaik)
- I've also made sure that the `kotlin.stdlib.default.dependency` is not set to `false` by accident.
- I've made sure my gradle is up to date (7.4.2 with Kotlin 1.5.30)
- Checked if `kotlin-gradle-plugin` is up to date since most of suggestions online led to plugin version being responsible for bundled stdlib
- updated project settings to use latest available Kotlin compiler and anything Kotlin-related (though it was 1.5 before so technically it shouldn't be required)

#### Outcome

###### Actual

The plugin distribution comes with latest (1.6.20 at the time of writing) `kotlin-stdlib` bundled but the moshi deserializer seems to still only have access to the IDE's built-in stdlib and still fails to get the `isValue` getter throwing errors at me

###### Expected

For the plugin to just work ;_; and use the bundled stdlib instead of ignoring it and using the IDE's one

What can be done to ensure proper `kotlin-stdlib` version is available to the plugin during runtime?

Comment: Can you attach a link to your project?

Comment: unfortunately not, the source is closed, but I can try to include some anonymized stuff if you tell me what you are interested in @vanyochek

Comment: I think you can ask the Moshi developers about your problem. Unfortunately, it's hard to help without a reproducer.